# Localization. Extending ASP.NET Resx Resource Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, globalization

For my website I have a custom resource provider for localization purposes (localized strings are stored in database). It works just fine, but I would like it to work with the default Resx Resource Provider: look up localized string in resx resources and if doesn't exist then pull it from the database.

But it looks that as soon as I change IIS globalization setting to use my own resource provider factory, then the default resx resource provider factory gets ignored.

I guess the solution would be to extend my own resource provider, but I can't find how to reference resx resources from inside of my resource provider.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

My answer below is wrong, as pointed out in the comments.  You can get the *ResXResourceProviderFactory* by using reflection as follows.

```
IResourceProvider resxProvider;
string typeName = "System.Web.Compilation.ResXResourceProviderFactory, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
ResourceProviderFactory factory = (ResourceProviderFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(typeName));
resxProvider = factory.CreateGlobalResourceProvider(classKey);
```

(Similar method to get the *Local* resources provider.)

Then, to get a resource, all that's needed is to call *GetObject*:

```
object resource = p.GetObject("ResourceKey", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en"));
```

---

You can use the [GetGlobalResourceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.getglobalresourceobject.aspx) and [GetLocalResourceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.getlocalresourceobject.aspx) methods (part of the *HttpContext* class) to work with .ResX files within your custom localization classes.

For example, to get a resource called "ResourceKey" from "MyResxFile.resx" (under *App_GlobalResources*), for the current culture, you would use this:

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(
    "MyResxFile", 
    "ResourceKey", 
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
);
```

Comment: `GetGlobalResourceObject` and `GetLocalResourceObject` are using current resource provider, in my case it's a custom provider. So calling `HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject` inside `GetObject` of my custom local resource provider will cause nothing but an infinite loop.

Comment: @MaksimVi. of course you're right, my mistake.  Please see my edit above.

Comment: alright, it solves the issue with GetGlobalResourceObject and GetLocalResourceObject, but `meta:resourcekey` attribute of my server controls is still ignored.

Comment: @MaksimVi. that's an interesting question; I haven't worked with those *meta* tags much, so I don't know how they work.  I think you should consider opening that as another question, asking how to override/customize the *meta:resourcekey*  behavior.

Comment: okay, i think I found a solution i'm going to try, but your answer is more relevant to my original question. Thank you.

Comment: I too have a problem with the meta:resourcekey attribute of some of my server controls being ignored. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68117643/asp-net-implicit-localization-not-firing-for-user-controls 

Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it looks that extending custom resource provider with the default resX resource provider doesn't fully solve the issue, since implicit localization expressions (`meta:resourcekey`) don't get localized.

The possible solution I found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx#exaspnet20rpm_topic6) is to use a custom ResourceExpressionBuilder:

> Configuring a custom provider is great for situations in which all
>   resources will be stored in an alternate location, and you don't plan
>   to leverage resources located in App_LocalResources and
>   App_GlobalResources, respectively. What if you want to support the
>   standard implementation for local and global resources (default
>   provider), while also having the option to pull some resources from
>   another source (custom provider)? You can achieve this by implementing
>   custom expressions that target the custom resource provider.

This will allow using resX resource provider for implicit and explicit localization and custom expressions for your custom resource provider:

```
<%-- Local ResX --%>
<asp:Localize ID="locLocal" runat="server" Text="DefaultLocal" meta:resourcekey="locLocal" />
<%-- Global ResX --%>
<asp:Localize ID="locGlobal" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:GlobalResourceStrings, locGlobal %>" />
<%-- Custom Resource Provider --%>
<asp:Localize ID="locCust" runat="server" Text="<%$ ExternalResources:MyResources|CustomResourceStrings, locCust %>" meta:localize="false" />
```

or in code as:

```
string s = (string)ExternalResourceExpressionBuilder.GetGlobalResourceObject("MyResources|CustomResourceStrings", "locCust");
```