# Extra level in resx fallback system

Tags: c#, .net, resx

In my current project we use resx files to have our application translated.
Now a request to brand our website requires for some strings to have slightly different translations.
I was thinking of extending Culture to BrandedCulture and then write a ResourceManager that uses the following fallback strategy:

1. Resx file for requeste culture and requested brand
2. Resx file for requested culture
3. Resx file for fallback culture

So basically add one extra check on top of the existing one.

I wanted to create a custom IResourceProvider that basically wraps the default ResourceProvider and use that one starting from step 2 (the normal behaviour), but I'm having difficulty instantiating/inheriting the default resource provider as it is internal.

Any suggestions? Am I going down the right path?

Might look duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331063/adding-levels-to-resx-files), but isn't

Comment: Customizing resource handling and localization in .NET can be pain! If I understood your problem right, it's about adding some brandmarks to already strings, like "®", right?

Comment: No it would be that a small subset of strings can have three versions: one general fallback, one translated and one branded translated. The branded translated text could potentially be completely different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use a custom resource provider to customize resource access. Use the right tools to request resources, based on your view engine in order for the resource provider factory to work.

## Custom resource provider factories

Since you are asking about a web project, you can implement your own [`ResourceProviderFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.resourceproviderfactory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and define it inside your web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization resourceProviderFactoryType="..." />
</system.web>
```

The above snippet should be self-descriptive. This factory may return your [custom resource provider implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.resourceproviderfactory.createglobalresourceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can also activate the standard resource provider for the default behaviour [using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336763/localization-extending-asp-net-resx-resource-provider).

```
public override IResourceProvider CreateGlobalResourceProvider(string classKey)
{
    var factory = (ResourceProviderFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Web.Compilation.ResXResourceProviderFactory, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"));
    var provider = factory.CreateGlobalResourceProvider(classKey);

    return new CustomResourceProvider(provider);
}
```

`CustomResourceProvider` holds an reference of the standard resource provider to implement the default behaviour. An detailled example of writing custom providers can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx).

However, I do not think that creating new cultures for a small subset of localized strings is a good idea. Cultures describe a certain locale and rules for formatting currencies, dates, numbers and so on. Available locales are standardised unter various ISO standards (639, 3166 and 15924). Your solution defines new cultures to model a subset of strings for an existing culture. That's not what cultures are defined for.

For example one of your strings that must be changed is in english. After it's "branding" it's still in english. Therefor the actual culture should stay the same.

You can challange this problem in different ways. Using a custom resource provider can be indeed a valid solution! By overwriting it's [`GetObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.iresourceprovider.getobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-method and checking for a defined prefix, for example:

```
public override object GetObject(string resourceKey, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (m_brandedMode)
        return m_provider("Branded" + resourceKey, culture) ?? m_provider(resourceKey, culture);
    else
        return m_provider(resourceKey, culture);
}
```

Here `m_brandedMode` is a simple boolean switch that may be set from the resource provider factory above. If it's enabled the custom resource provider queries for the string with a "Branded"-prefix. If there's no string matching, it uses the default implementation.

Inside your resource file for english you would have two versions strings that differ based on the branding: *MyString* and *BrandedMyString*. They both share the same culture, but they are queried by the resource provider based on an application setting.

Of course this is just an example. You can also implement different data sources for branded and unbranded strings, even if this might be a little more work to do. However, I suggest not touching the cultures and also not touching the default behaviour. Resource management is sometimes a little bit tricky in .NET.

## Using resources (the right way)

Based on your view engine there you have to change the way of accessing localized strings in order for the environment to pick up your custom factory. Note that I only tested this for web views with ASPX and Razor view engines, but I think this can be similarly adopted to offline applications with WinForms and WPF.

Typically if you add default resources to your project, a designer generated wrapper around it get's generated. If your default resource file is called *Resources*, the designer generates a class *Resources* within the *Resources.Designer.cs* file. This is pretty handy but misleading since it apparently is not intented to be used as localization source, but for symbols, icons and all this other data want to embed into your assembly. So the first step to take is decide how you want to localize your project. This can typically be done by view or globally.

Localizing by view means nothing more than you put a resource file for each view (with the same name, something like *Index.cshtml.resx*) inside the directory your view file is located. Globally lobalizing means that all strings for one culture go into one resource file that is typically located inside the **App_GlobalResources** directory. However this is not mandatory. In fact the resource file can be embedded into your assembly, another assembly or located somewhere else.

### Localizing ASPX views

I am starting with localized strings for ASPX, because it's actually easier (which surprised me). In ASPX you are using the `<%$` expression builder syntax to access resources:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:MyResource, Test %>" />
```

This tells the compiler to use the resource *Test* from the *MyResource* resource container (by default an resource file). The expression results into a call to `CreateGlobalResourceProvider("MyResource")`. The returned provider get's a call to `GetObject("Test")`.

I did not dig deeper into this, but apparently it is not directly possible to localize ASPX views locally. However, this should not be to hard and self-speaking. (The resulting call to the factory goes to `GetLocalResourceProvider` instead of `GetGlobalResourceProvider`)

### Localizing Razor views

The tricky thing is that you typically use the auto-generated `Resource` class like so:

```
@MyResource.Test
```

This bypasses the resource provider generation by using the standard resource manager. The correct way to access localized strings is to use `HttpContext`:

```
@HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MyResource", "Test")
```

Gotcha! This calls `GetGlobalResourceProvider("MyResource")` on the custom resource provider factory. The rest is just like described previously. In a similar way you can use `@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", "Test")` in order to request a local resource.

I have no idea why this is not a standard extension, but you can wrap this inside fancy helper methods:

```
public static string Resource(this HtmlHelper helper, string resourceName, string resourceKey)
{
    return helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(resourceName, resourceKey).ToString();
}

public static string Resource(this WebViewPage page, string resourceKey)
{
    return page.ViewContext.HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(page.VirtualPath, resourceKey).ToString();
}
```

The following commands will either request global or local strings:

```
@Html.Resource("MyResources", "Test");    // Global resource "Test" from "MyResources" container.
@this.Resource("Test");                   // Local resource "Test".
```

Tricky, but it should do the job!

Comment: It will be both in web and class library. The prefixes feels dirty however.

Comment: Indeed, but it should give you at least a small hint where to start :)

Comment: The referenced documentation is indeed the one example that keeps popping up, but it is outdated as resources should now be implemented with InternalGetResourceSet.
I personally don't get why this has to be this hard. As I already spent too much time on this, however, I will go with the prefix method. Thx

Comment: No worries. I know that resources are like the dark side of .NET. Afaik it's the only part that does not support generics yet. Personally, I had the requirement of adding new locales to existing environments at runtime and ended up with writing a small "compiler" for satellite assemblies, because providing localized resources from another data source was way harder to implement and maintain.

Comment: The globalization config tag is not picked up. For testing purposes I created a new MVC (razor) site added the config tag, created a factory with notimplemented exceptions everywhere. The factory never gets called. Resharper fixes the config tag's value to the correct one when I intentionally break it, so I'm rather sure that ones ok too. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you specify the full type name?

Comment: Jep. I also tried intentionally mistyping it, but resharper stepped in and filled everything out.

Comment: Got it! I've setup an test project on my own, following the code sample (here)[bit.ly/1fXzlwh]. Using the Razor view engine, you typically directly access `@Resources.Test`. However, this invokes the designer generated resource provider. I've added another view using `aspx` view engine and added a label with `Text="<%§ Resources:Resources, Test %>`. This somehow worked. Note that Visual Studio quietly crashes when you got your `NotImplementException`s inside the method bodys. I am still searching how to access resources "correctly" using Razor...

Comment: Okay, you have to use `@HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resources", "Test")` where *Resources* is the name of your resource file and *Test* is the name of the resource. If you are localizing per-view you can use `GetLocalResourceObject` and their respecitve overwrites within your resource factory. I will update the answer.

Comment: @BorisCallens: See my updated answer. Hope this tames the beast! :)

Comment: Thx for the perseverance :) I worked my way around the issue by now, thinking I would revisit it when I found a better solution. This looks to be it. I will have to have a look when I can get to my source again.